# Why I can't use "!" shortcut in visual studio to instantly popped out !doctype etc

Tags: javascript

I was looking at javascript lecture video where the lecturer type "!" then tab and the following shows up instantly (but i can't do it in my visual studio, i wonder why):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en">     
<head>
<meta charset="UTF 8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
```

Comment: You haven't enabled emmet https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet

Comment: Check if Emmet is installed and / or enabled